# pandas read csv does not separating columns, too many columns?

Tags: pandas, input

I have tried many ways, but it still did not work
below is the data of the first row, how can I seperate them? is it because the number of column exceeds the limit?
[image]

1, Car, 48.85, 9.770344, 37.977391, 23.737688, 4.9178, 0.0518, -0.0299, 0.000000, 37.977391, 23.737688, 4.9207, -0.0124, -0.0354, 0.040000, 37.977391, 23.737688, 4.9160, -0.0519, -0.0413, 0.080000, 37.977390, 23.737688, 4.9057, -0.0914, -0.0478, 0.120000, 37.977390, 23.737689, 4.8871, -0.1679, -0.0550, 0.160000, 37.977389, 23.737689, 4.8547, -0.2815, -0.0628, 0.200000, 37.977389, 23.737689, 4.8033, -0.4320, -0.0713, 0.240000, 37.977388, 23.737690, 4.7318, -0.5617, -0.0804, 0.280000, 37.977388, 23.737690, 4.6442, -0.6543, -0.0905, 0.320000, 37.977388, 23.737690, 4.5437, -0.7413, -0.1017, 0.360000, 37.977387, 23.737690, 4.4311, -0.8227, -0.1143, 0.400000, 37.977387, 23.737691, 4.3046, -0.9354, -0.1285, 0.440000, 37.977386, 23.737691, 4.1600, -1.0729, -0.1439, 0.480000, 37.977386, 23.737691, 4.4411, -0.5617, -0.0949, 0.520000, 37.977385, 23.737692, 4.3561, -0.6183, -0.1044, 0.560000, 37.977385, 23.737692, 4.2639, -0.6621, -0.1133, 0.600000, 37.977384, 23.737692, 4.1654, -0.7059, -0.1219, 0.640000, 37.977384, 23.737692, 4.0595, -0.7660, -0.1298, 0.680000, 37.977384, 23.737693, 3.9439, -0.8388, -0.1369, 0.720000, 37.977383, 23.737693, 3.8183, -0.9065, -0.1430, 0.760000, 37.977383, 23.737693, 3.6842, -0.9561, -0.1484, 0.800000, 37.977383, 23.737693, 3.5447, -0.9812, -0.1530, 0.840000, 37.977382, 23.737694, 3.4018, -1.0035, -0.1567, 0.880000, 37.977382, 23.737694, 3.2559, -1.0228, -0.1593, 0.920000, 37.977382, 23.737694, 3.1076, -1.0370, -0.1610, 0.960000, 37.977381, 23.737694, 2.9576, -1.0458, -0.1618, 1.000000, 37.977381, 23.737695, 2.8081, -1.0303, -0.1618, 1.040000, 37.977381, 23.737695, 2.6611, -1.0118, -0.1604, 1.080000, 37.977381, 23.737695, 2.5170, -0.9904, -0.1573, 1.120000, 37.977381, 23.737695, 2.3763, -0.9638, -0.1525, 1.160000, 37.977380, 23.737695, 2.2398, -0.9320, -0.1460, 1.200000, 37.977380, 23.737695, 2.1096, -0.8757, -0.1377, 1.240000, 37.977380, 23.737695, 1.9883, -0.8090, -0.1276, 1.280000, 37.977380, 23.737696, 1.8768, -0.7394, -0.1154, 1.320000, 37.977380, 23.737696, 1.7751, -0.6739, -0.1014, 1.360000, 37.977380, 23.737696, 1.6823, -0.6145, -0.0855, 1.400000, 37.977380, 23.737696, 1.5988, -0.5450, -0.0675, 1.440000, 37.977380, 23.737696, 1.5264, -0.4611, -0.0477, 1.480000, 37.977380, 23.737696, 1.4666, -0.3696, -0.0283, 1.520000, 37.977380, 23.737696, 1.4197, -0.2816, -0.0099, 1.560000, 37.977379, 23.737696, 1.3844, -0.2080, 0.0065, 1.600000, 37.977379, 23.737696, 1.3586, -0.1507, 0.0209, 1.640000, 37.977379, 23.737696, 1.3406, -0.0995, 0.0337, 1.680000, 37.977379, 23.737696, 1.3298, -0.0502, 0.0457, 1.720000, 37.977379, 23.737697, 1.3266, 0.0054, 0.0567, 1.760000, 37.977379, 23.737697, 1.3316, 0.0637, 0.0666, 1.800000, 37.977379, 23.737697, 1.3438, 0.1067, 0.0751, 1.840000, 37.977379, 23.737697, 1.3615, 0.1384, 0.0826, 1.880000, 37.977379, 23.737697, 1.3829, 0.1588, 0.0891, 1.920000, 37.977379, 23.737697, 1.4077, 0.1854, 0.0946, 1.960000, 37.977379, 23.737697, 1.4367, 0.2183, 0.0989, 2.000000, 37.977378, 23.737697, 1.4694, 0.2359, 0.1020, 2.040000, 37.977378, 23.737697, 1.5038, 0.2422, 0.1042, 2.080000, 37.977378, 23.737697, 1.5384, 0.2371, 0.1055, 2.120000, 37.977378, 23.737698, 1.5726, 0.2383, 0.1053, 2.160000, 37.977378, 23.737698, 1.6074, 0.2457, 0.1033, 2.200000, 37.977378, 23.737698, 1.6422, 0.2379, 0.0995, 2.240000, 37.977378, 23.737698, 1.6752, 0.2193, 0.0940, 2.280000, 37.977377, 23.737698, 1.7046, 0.1895, 0.0867, 2.320000, 37.977377, 23.737698, 1.7296, 0.1574, 0.0773, 2.360000, 37.977377, 23.737698, 1.7503, 0.1307, 0.0657, 2.400000, 37.977377, 23.737698, 1.7669, 0.0993, 0.0521, 2.440000, 37.977377, 23.737698, 1.7787, 0.0652, 0.0367, 2.480000, 37.977377, 23.737699, 1.7857, 0.0317, 0.0203, 2.520000, 37.977376, 23.737699, 1.7876, -0.0060, 0.0035, 2.560000, 37.977376, 23.737699, 1.7842, -0.0411, -0.0115, 2.600000, 37.977376, 23.737699, 1.7765, -0.0660, -0.0241, 2.640000, 37.977376, 23.737699, 1.7656, -0.0855, -0.0344, 2.680000, 37.977376, 23.737699, 1.7524, -0.0975, -0.0423, 2.720000, 37.977376, 23.737699, 1.7377, -0.1062, -0.0481, 2.760000, 37.977375, 23.737699, 1.7217, -0.1158, -0.0525, 2.800000, 37.977375, 23.737699, 1.7049, -0.1182, -0.0557, 2.840000, 37.977375, 23.737700, 1.6876, -0.1215, -0.0576, 2.880000, 37.977375, 23.737700, 1.6698, -0.1257, -0.0582, 2.920000, 37.977375, 23.737700, 1.6517, -0.1266, -0.0577, 2.960000, 37.977375, 23.737700, 1.6336, -0.1243, -0.0561, 3.000000, 37.977375, 23.737700, 1.6164, -0.1147, -0.0534, 3.040000, 37.977374, 23.737700, 1.6005, -0.1061, -0.0498, 3.080000, 37.977374, 23.737700, 1.5858, -0.0983, -0.0453, 3.120000, 37.977374, 23.737700, 1.5724, -0.0873, -0.0402, 3.160000, 37.977374, 23.737700, 1.5609, -0.0730, -0.0342, 3.200000, 37.977374, 23.737700, 1.5519, -0.0515, -0.0275, 3.240000, 37.977374, 23.737701, 1.5460, -0.0307, -0.0199, 3.280000, 37.977374, 23.737701, 1.5430, -0.0108, -0.0118, 3.320000, 37.977374, 23.737701, 1.5430, 0.0115, -0.0031, 3.360000, 37.977373, 23.737701, 1.5465, 0.0368, 0.0062, 3.400000, 37.977373, 23.737701, 1.5542, 0.0698, 0.0164, 3.440000, 37.977373, 23.737701, 1.5670, 0.1081, 0.0272, 3.480000, 37.977373, 23.737701, 1.5853, 0.1467, 0.0382, 3.520000, 37.977373, 23.737701, 1.6091, 0.1830, 0.0491, 3.560000, 37.977373, 23.737701, 1.6377, 0.2140, 0.0593, 3.600000, 37.977373, 23.737701, 1.6704, 0.2403, 0.0685, 3.640000, 37.977373, 23.737702, 1.7071, 0.2695, 0.0768, 3.680000, 37.977373, 23.737702, 1.7480, 0.2993, 0.0843, 3.720000, 37.977372, 23.737702, 1.7930, 0.3255, 0.0908, 3.760000, 37.977372, 23.737702, 1.8414, 0.3460, 0.0960, 3.800000, 37.977372, 23.737702, 1.8918, 0.3548, 0.1000, 3.840000, 37.977372, 23.737702, 1.9435, 0.3634, 0.1029, 3.880000, 37.977372, 23.737702, 1.9964, 0.3717, 0.1045, 3.920000, 37.977372, 23.737702, 2.0503, 0.3764, 0.1050, 3.960000, 37.977371, 23.737702, 2.1046, 0.3775, 0.1043, 4.000000, 37.977371, 23.737703, 2.1582, 0.3670, 0.1026, 4.040000, 37.977371, 23.737703, 2.2102, 0.3562, 0.0999, 4.080000, 37.977371, 23.737703, 2.2607, 0.3451, 0.0960, 4.120000, 37.977371, 23.737703, 2.3094, 0.3304, 0.0911, 4.160000, 37.977370, 23.737703, 2.3556, 0.3122, 0.0853, 4.200000, 37.977370, 23.737703, 2.3984, 0.2823, 0.0788, 4.240000, 37.977370, 23.737703, 2.4369, 0.2516, 0.0714, 4.280000, 37.977370, 23.737704, 2.4709, 0.2206, 0.0630, 4.320000, 37.977369, 23.737704, 2.5002, 0.1866, 0.0537, 4.360000, 37.977369, 23.737704, 2.5244, 0.1498, 0.0434, 4.400000, 37.977369, 23.737704, 2.5426, 0.1025, 0.0323, 4.440000, 37.977369, 23.737704, 2.5534, 0.0477, 0.0204, 4.480000, 37.977368, 23.737704, 2.5563, -0.0077, 0.0082, 4.520000, 37.977368, 23.737704, 2.5513, -0.0607, -0.0041, 4.560000, 37.977368, 23.737705, 2.5393, -0.1061, -0.0160, 4.600000, 37.977368, 23.737705, 2.5213, -0.1438, -0.0275, 4.640000, 37.977367, 23.737705, 2.4977, -0.1844, -0.0385, 4.680000, 37.977367, 23.737705, 2.4683, -0.2247, -0.0487, 4.720000, 37.977367, 23.737705, 2.4333, -0.2605, -0.0579, 4.760000, 37.977367, 23.737705, 2.3937, -0.2895, -0.0663, 4.800000, 37.977366, 23.737705, 2.3511, -0.3025, -0.0740, 4.840000, 37.977366, 23.737705, 2.3066, -0.3149, -0.0807, 4.880000, 37.977366, 23.737706, 2.2605, -0.3264, -0.0864, 4.920000, 37.977366, 23.737706, 2.2129, -0.3335, -0.0911, 4.960000, 37.977365, 23.737706, 2.1647, -0.3360, -0.0949, 5.000000, 37.977365, 23.737706, 2.1173, -0.3228, -0.0978, 5.040000, 37.977365, 23.737706, 2.0718, -0.3087, -0.0998, 5.080000, 37.977365, 23.737706, 2.0285, -0.2939, -0.1008, 5.120000, 37.977365, 23.737706, 1.9875, -0.2746, -0.1008, 5.160000, 37.977365, 23.737706, 1.9497, -0.2507, -0.0999, 5.200000, 37.977364, 23.737707, 1.9165, -0.2110, -0.0981, 5.240000, 37.977364, 23.737707, 1.8890, -0.1702, -0.0953, 5.280000, 37.977364, 23.737707, 1.8675, -0.1287, -0.0916, 5.320000, 37.977364, 23.737707, 1.8523, -0.0826, -0.0870, 5.360000, 37.977364, 23.737707, 1.8440, -0.0325, -0.0815, 5.400000, 37.977364, 23.737707, 1.8440, 0.0321, -0.0750, 5.440000, 37.977364, 23.737707, 1.8540, 0.1068, -0.0675, 5.480000, 37.977364, 23.737707, 1.8747, 0.1818, -0.0593, 5.520000, 37.977363, 23.737707, 1.9061, 0.2537, -0.0507, 5.560000, 37.977363, 23.737707, 1.9471, 0.3157, -0.0421, 5.600000, 37.977363, 23.737708, 1.9963, 0.3671, -0.0334, 5.640000, 37.977363, 23.737708, 2.0531, 0.4226, -0.0247, 5.680000, 37.977363, 23.737708, 2.1179, 0.4776, -0.0159, 5.720000, 37.977363, 23.737708, 2.1902, 0.5257, -0.0071, 5.760000, 37.977363, 23.737708, 2.2686, 0.5640, 0.0011, 5.800000, 37.977362, 23.737708, 2.3510, 0.5805, 0.0088, 5.840000, 37.977362, 23.737708, 2.4358, 0.5965, 0.0161, 5.880000, 37.977362, 23.737709, 2.5228, 0.6120, 0.0230, 5.920000, 37.977362, 23.737709, 2.6115, 0.6206, 0.0295, 5.960000, 37.977362, 23.737709, 2.7010, 0.6224, 0.0353, 6.000000, 37.977361, 23.737709, 2.7892, 0.6024, 0.0404, 6.040000, 37.977361, 23.737709, 2.8745, 0.5818, 0.0450, 6.080000, 37.977361, 23.737710, 2.9568, 0.5608, 0.0490, 6.120000, 37.977361, 23.737710, 3.0355, 0.5330, 0.0525, 6.160000, 37.977360, 23.737710, 3.1098, 0.4984, 0.0553, 6.200000, 37.977360, 23.737710, 3.1775, 0.4419, 0.0576, 6.240000, 37.977360, 23.737711, 3.2362, 0.3740, 0.0594, 6.280000, 37.977360, 23.737711, 3.2851, 0.3056, 0.0606, 6.320000, 37.977359, 23.737711, 3.3249, 0.2465, 0.0612, 6.360000, 37.977359, 23.737711, 3.3568, 0.1970, 0.0613, 6.400000, 37.977359, 23.737712, 3.3813, 0.1427, 0.0610, 6.440000, 37.977358, 23.737712, 3.3969, 0.0741, 0.0602, 6.480000, 37.977358, 23.737712, 3.4018, -0.0054, 0.0590, 6.520000, 37.977358, 23.737712, 3.3956, -0.0805, 0.0576, 6.560000, 37.977357, 23.737713, 3.3797, -0.1413, 0.0563, 6.600000, 37.977357, 23.737713, 3.3560, -0.1875, 0.0552, 6.640000, 37.977357, 23.737713, 3.3264, -0.2242, 0.0542, 6.680000, 37.977356, 23.737713, 3.2915, -0.2605, 0.0533, 6.720000, 37.977356, 23.737714, 3.2503, -0.3108, 0.0524, 6.760000, 37.977356, 23.737714, 3.2013, -0.3705, 0.0516, 6.800000, 37.977355, 23.737714, 3.1442, -0.4228, 0.0508, 6.840000, 37.977355, 23.737714, 3.0807, -0.4586, 0.0501, 6.880000, 37.977355, 23.737714, 3.0133, -0.4780, 0.0495, 6.920000, 37.977355, 23.737715, 2.9420, -0.5114, 0.0489, 6.960000, 37.977354, 23.737715, 2.8650, -0.5589, 0.0483, 7.000000, 37.977354, 23.737715, 2.7816, -0.5990, 0.0476, 7.040000, 37.977354, 23.737715, 2.6937, -0.6226, 0.0468, 7.080000, 37.977354, 23.737715, 2.6035, -0.6297, 0.0460, 7.120000, 37.977354, 23.737715, 2.5113, -0.6507, 0.0450, 7.160000, 37.977353, 23.737716, 2.4151, -0.6858, 0.0439, 7.200000, 37.977353, 23.737716, 2.3144, -0.7134, 0.0426, 7.240000, 37.977353, 23.737716, 2.2103, -0.7313, 0.0413, 7.280000, 37.977353, 23.737716, 2.1049, -0.7327, 0.0398, 7.320000, 37.977353, 23.737716, 1.9998, -0.7272, 0.0383, 7.360000, 37.977352, 23.737716, 1.8952, -0.7258, 0.0367, 7.400000, 37.977352, 23.737716, 1.7908, -0.7236, 0.0351, 7.440000, 37.977352, 23.737717, 1.6872, -0.7160, 0.0333, 7.480000, 37.977352, 23.737717, 1.5833, -0.7270, 0.0316, 7.520000, 37.977352, 23.737717, 1.4829, -0.6960, 0.0299, 7.560000, 37.977352, 23.737717, 1.3868, -0.6678, 0.0281, 7.600000, 37.977351, 23.737717, 1.2944, -0.6444, 0.0264, 7.640000, 37.977351, 23.737717, 1.2049, -0.6281, 0.0246, 7.680000, 37.977351, 23.737717, 1.1169, -0.6234, 0.0229, 7.720000, 37.977351, 23.737717, 1.0293, -0.6153, 0.0213, 7.760000, 37.977351, 23.737717, 0.9429, -0.6068, 0.0196, 7.800000, 37.977351, 23.737717, 0.8581, -0.5930, 0.0180, 7.840000, 37.977351, 23.737717, 0.7757, -0.5742, 0.0166, 7.880000, 37.977351, 23.737717, 0.6964, -0.5501, 0.0158, 7.920000, 37.977351, 23.737717, 0.6204, -0.5286, 0.0143, 7.960000, 37.977351, 23.737717, 0.5473, -0.5110, 0.0131, 8.000000, 37.977351, 23.737717, 0.4773, -0.4863, 0.0117, 8.040000, 37.977351, 23.737717, 0.4112, -0.4562, 0.0103, 8.080000, 37.977351, 23.737717, 0.3498, -0.4208, 0.0090, 8.120000, 37.977351, 23.737717, 0.2933, -0.3892, 0.0077, 8.160000, 37.977351, 23.737717, 0.2405, -0.3690, 0.0077, 8.200000, 37.977351, 23.737717, 0.1925, -0.3337, 0.0069, 8.240000, 37.977351, 23.737717, 0.1496, -0.2968, 0.0060, 8.280000, 37.977351, 23.737717, 0.1127, -0.2527, 0.0053, 8.320000, 37.977351, 23.737717, 0.0826, -0.2006, 0.0048, 8.360000, 37.977351, 23.737717, 0.0594, -0.1573, 0.0041, 8.400000, 37.977351, 23.737717, 0.0424, -0.0710, 0.0030, 8.440000, 37.977351, 23.737717, 0.0360, -0.0097, 0.0026, 8.480000, 37.977351, 23.737717, 0.0389, 0.0577, 0.0024, 8.520000, 37.977351, 23.737717, 0.0510, 0.1194, 0.0023, 8.560000, 37.977351, 23.737717, 0.0734, 0.1993, 0.0023, 8.600000, 37.977351, 23.737717, 0.1028, 0.2464, 0.0023, 8.640000, 37.977351, 23.737717, 0.1399, 0.3060, 0.0023, 8.680000, 37.977351, 23.737717, 0.1852, 0.3597, 0.0023, 8.720000, 37.977351, 23.737717, 0.2373, 0.4008, 0.0023, 8.760000, 37.977351, 23.737717, 0.2947, 0.4341, 0.0022, 8.800000, 37.977351, 23.737717, 0.3561, 0.4491, 0.0019, 8.840000, 37.977351, 23.737717, 0.4206, 0.4769, 0.0019, 8.880000, 37.977351, 23.737717, 0.4896, 0.5122, 0.0018, 8.920000, 37.977351, 23.737717, 0.5629, 0.5368, 0.0016, 8.960000, 37.977351, 23.737717, 0.6390, 0.5503, 0.0008, 9.000000, 37.977351, 23.737717, 0.7161, 0.5517, 0.0007, 9.040000, 37.977351, 23.737717, 0.7938, 0.5608, 0.0003, 9.080000, 37.977351, 23.737717, 0.8733, 0.5756, 0.0001, 9.120000, 37.977351, 23.737718, 0.9541, 0.5795, -0.0000, 9.160000, 37.977351, 23.737718, 1.0347, 0.5724, -0.0001, 9.200000, 37.977350, 23.737718, 1.1134, 0.5543, -0.0002, 9.240000, 37.977350, 23.737718, 1.1900, 0.5425, -0.0013, 9.280000, 37.977350, 23.737718, 1.2640, 0.5284, -0.0016, 9.320000, 37.977350, 23.737718, 1.3363, 0.5205, -0.0016, 9.360000, 37.977350, 23.737718, 1.4076, 0.5132, -0.0017, 9.400000, 37.977350, 23.737718, 1.4776, 0.5033, -0.0017, 9.440000, 37.977350, 23.737718, 1.5462, 0.4938, -0.0016, 9.480000, 37.977349, 23.737718, 1.6131, 0.4350, -0.0009, 9.520000, 37.977349, 23.737719, 1.6735, 0.4043, -0.0008, 9.560000, 37.977349, 23.737719, 1.7293, 0.3705, -0.0008, 9.600000, 37.977349, 23.737719, 1.7805, 0.3406, -0.0008, 9.640000, 37.977349, 23.737719, 1.8274, 0.3099, -0.0008, 9.680000, 37.977349, 23.737719, 1.8692, 0.2709, -0.0008, 9.720000, 37.977348, 23.737719, 1.9046, 0.2208, -0.0008, 9.760000, 37.977348, 23.737719, 1.9327, 0.1694, -0.0007, 9.800000, 37.977348, 23.737720, 1.9539, 0.1255, -0.0007, 9.840000, 37.977348, 23.737720, 1.9698, 0.0950, -0.0006, 9.880000, 37.977348, 23.737720, 1.9822, 0.0781, -0.0006, 9.920000, 37.977348, 23.737720, 1.9915, 0.0501, -0.0005, 9.960000, 37.977347, 23.737720, 1.9959, 0.0110, -0.0004, 10.000000, 37.977347, 23.737720, 1.9952, -0.0206, -0.0003, 10.040000, 37.977347, 23.737720, 1.9909, -0.0385, -0.0001, 10.080000, 37.977347, 23.737721, 1.9851, -0.0429, 0.0000, 10.120000, 37.977347, 23.737721, 1.9778, -0.0584, 0.0002, 10.160000, 37.977347, 23.737721, 1.9675, -0.0849, 0.0004, 10.200000, 37.977346, 23.737721, 1.9539, -0.1040, 0.0006, 10.240000, 37.977346, 23.737721, 1.9387, -0.1072, 0.0009, 10.280000, 37.977346, 23.737721, 1.9240, -0.0969, 0.0011, 10.320000, 37.977346, 23.737721, 1.9103, -0.0922, 0.0013, 10.360000, 37.977346, 23.737721, 1.8964, -0.1019, 0.0016, 10.400000, 37.977346, 23.737722, 1.8803, -0.1213, 0.0018, 10.440000, 37.977345, 23.737722, 1.8612, -0.1447, 0.0021, 10.480000, 37.977345, 23.737722, 1.8388, -0.1657, 0.0023, 10.520000, 37.977345, 23.737722, 1.8140, -0.1794, 0.0025, 10.560000, 37.977345, 23.737722, 1.7874, -0.1890, 0.0026, 10.600000, 37.977345, 23.737722, 1.7592, -0.2036, 0.0027, 10.640000, 37.977345, 23.737722, 1.7277, -0.2328, 0.0028, 10.680000, 37.977344, 23.737723, 1.6915, -0.2709, 0.0029, 10.720000, 37.977344, 23.737723, 1.6503, -0.3008, 0.0029, 10.760000, 37.977344, 23.737723, 1.6060, -0.3149, 0.0029, 10.800000, 37.977344, 23.737723, 1.5607, -0.3147, 0.0028, 10.840000, 37.977344, 23.737723, 1.5151, -0.3181, 0.0027, 10.880000, 37.977344, 23.737723, 1.4688, -0.3250, 0.0026, 10.920000, 37.977344, 23.737723, 1.4221, -0.3235, 0.0026, 10.960000, 37.977343, 23.737723, 1.3762, -0.3137, 0.0026, 11.000000, 37.977343, 23.737723, 1.3328, -0.2895, 0.0027, 11.040000, 37.977343, 23.737724, 1.2926, -0.2687, 0.0027, 11.080000, 37.977343, 23.737724, 1.2551, -0.2515, 0.0024, 11.120000, 37.977343, 23.737724, 1.2208, -0.2260, 0.0017, 11.160000, 37.977343, 23.737724, 1.1907, -0.1923, 0.0008, 11.200000, 37.977343, 23.737724, 1.1664, -0.1442, -0.0004, 11.240000, 37.977343, 23.737724, 1.1503, -0.0800, -0.0017, 11.280000, 37.977343, 23.737724, 1.1431, -0.0193, -0.0029, 11.320000, 37.977343, 23.737724, 1.1430, 0.0180, -0.0041, 11.360000, 37.977343, 23.737724, 1.1468, 0.0342, -0.0053, 11.400000, 37.977343, 23.737724, 1.1521, 0.0390, -0.0064, 11.440000, 37.977342, 23.737724, 1.1589, 0.0557, -0.0074, 11.480000, 37.977342, 23.737724, 1.1695, 0.0920, -0.0079, 11.520000, 37.977342, 23.737724, 1.1850, 0.1227, -0.0077, 11.560000, 37.977342, 23.737724, 1.2040, 0.1415, -0.0067, 11.600000, 37.977342, 23.737724, 1.2250, 0.1508, -0.0048, 11.640000, 37.977342, 23.737724, 1.2459, 0.1390, -0.0022, 11.680000, 37.977342, 23.737725, 1.2652, 0.1296, 0.0003, 11.720000, 37.977342, 23.737725, 1.2857, 0.1552, 0.0024, 11.760000, 37.977342, 23.737725, 1.3121, 0.2104, 0.0041, 11.800000, 37.977342, 23.737725, 1.3476, 0.2829, 0.0055, 11.840000, 37.977342, 23.737725, 1.3914, 0.3259, 0.0065, 11.880000, 37.977341, 23.737725, 1.4393, 0.3395, 0.0077, 11.920000, 37.977341, 23.737725, 1.4917, 0.3883, 0.0090, 11.960000, 37.977341, 23.737725, 1.5537, 0.4724, 0.0105, 12.000000, 37.977341, 23.737725, 1.6290, 0.5738, 0.0123, 12.040000, 37.977341, 23.737726, 1.7168, 0.6457, 0.0143, 12.080000, 37.977341, 23.737726, 1.8129, 0.6881, 0.0163, 12.120000, 37.977340, 23.737726, 1.9175, 0.7656, 0.0183, 12.160000, 37.977340, 23.737726, 2.0359, 0.8783, 0.0206, 12.200000, 37.977340, 23.737726, 2.1717, 1.0083, 0.0234, 12.240000, 37.977340, 23.737726, 2.3253, 1.1252, 0.0265, 12.280000, 37.977340, 23.737726, 2.4937, 1.2128, 0.0298, 12.320000, 37.977340, 23.737726, 2.6740, 1.2915, 0.0333, 12.360000, 37.977340, 23.737726, 2.8664, 1.3810, 0.0368, 12.400000, 37.977339, 23.737727, 3.0733, 1.4927, 0.0403, 12.440000, 37.977339, 23.737727, 3.2985, 1.6354, 0.0438, 12.480000, 37.977339, 23.737727, 3.5455, 1.7943, 0.0474, 12.520000, 37.977339, 23.737727, 3.8136, 1.9298, 0.0510, 12.560000, 37.977339, 23.737727, 4.0990, 2.0343, 0.0542, 12.600000, 37.977338, 23.737727, 4.3987, 2.1273, 0.0569, 12.640000, 37.977338, 23.737728, 4.7125, 2.2311, 0.0589, 12.680000, 37.977338, 23.737728, 5.0426, 2.3545, 0.0602, 12.720000, 37.977337, 23.737728, 5.3915, 2.4910, 0.0610, 12.760000, 37.977337, 23.737729, 5.7593, 2.6173, 0.0621, 12.800000, 37.977336, 23.737729, 6.1429, 2.7103, 0.0637, 12.840000, 37.977336, 23.737729, 6.5381, 2.7789, 0.0659, 12.880000, 37.977335, 23.737730, 6.9415, 2.8231, 0.0687, 12.920000, 37.977335, 23.737730, 7.3521, 2.8807, 0.0720, 12.960000, 37.977334, 23.737731, 7.7721, 2.9515, 0.0755, 13.000000, 37.977333, 23.737731, 8.1998, 2.9889, 0.0790, 13.040000, 37.977333, 23.737732, 8.6311, 3.0019, 0.0825, 13.080000, 37.977332, 23.737732, 9.0626, 2.9903, 0.0859, 13.120000, 37.977331, 23.737733, 9.4933, 2.9921, 0.0893, 13.160000, 37.977330, 23.737734, 9.9252, 3.0071, 0.0928, 13.200000, 37.977329, 23.737734, 10.3569, 2.9887, 0.0966, 13.240000, 37.977328, 23.737735, 10.7843, 2.9473, 0.1007, 13.280000, 37.977327, 23.737736, 11.2040, 2.8814, 0.1049, 13.320000, 37.977326, 23.737736, 11.6138, 2.8106, 0.1094, 13.360000, 37.977325, 23.737737, 12.0143, 2.7511, 0.1142, 13.400000, 37.977324, 23.737738, 12.4053, 2.6806, 0.1192, 13.440000, 37.977323, 23.737739, 12.7858, 2.6042, 0.1246, 13.480000, 37.977322, 23.737739, 13.1554, 2.5290, 0.1307, 13.520000, 37.977321, 23.737740, 13.5136, 2.4450, 0.1376, 13.560000, 37.977319, 23.737741, 13.8600, 2.3670, 0.1452, 13.600000, 37.977318, 23.737742, 14.1969, 2.3112, 0.1537, 13.640000, 37.977317, 23.737743, 14.5265, 2.2667, 0.1628, 13.680000, 37.977316, 23.737744, 14.8508, 2.2384, 0.1726, 13.720000, 37.977314, 23.737745, 15.1716, 2.2175, 0.1831, 13.760000, 37.977313, 23.737746, 15.4894, 2.1953, 0.1941, 13.800000, 37.977311, 23.737747, 15.8051, 2.1896, 0.2058, 13.840000, 37.977310, 23.737748, 16.1198, 2.1820, 0.2181, 13.880000, 37.977309, 23.737749, 16.4333, 2.1724, 0.2310, 13.920000, 37.977307, 23.737750, 16.7460, 2.1703, 0.2444, 13.960000, 37.977306, 23.737751, 17.0589, 2.1757, 0.2584, 14.000000, 37.977304, 23.737752, 17.3738, 2.1975, 0.2728, 14.040000, 37.977303, 23.737753, 17.6917, 2.2174, 0.2878, 14.080000, 37.977301, 23.737754, 18.0123, 2.2352, 0.3032, 14.120000, 37.977299, 23.737755, 18.3360, 2.2606, 0.3190, 14.160000, 37.977298, 23.737756, 18.6638, 2.2934, 0.3352, 14.200000, 37.977296, 23.737757, 18.9976, 2.3427, 0.3518, 14.240000, 37.977294, 23.737758, 19.3387, 2.3946, 0.3687, 14.280000, 37.977293, 23.737759, 19.6871, 2.4445, 0.3861, 14.320000, 37.977291, 23.737760, 20.0427, 2.4937, 0.4039, 14.360000, 37.977289, 23.737761, 20.4053, 2.5436, 0.4219, 14.400000, 37.977287, 23.737763, 20.7760, 2.6051, 0.4403, 14.440000, 37.977286, 23.737764, 21.1565, 2.6788, 0.4594, 14.480000, 37.977284, 23.737765, 21.5479, 2.7572, 0.4807, 14.520000, 37.977282, 23.737766, 21.9502, 2.8305, 0.5045, 14.560000, 37.977280, 23.737767, 22.3622, 2.8916, 0.5304, 14.600000, 37.977278, 23.737769, 22.7822, 2.9416, 0.5584, 14.640000, 37.977276, 23.737770, 23.2094, 2.9924, 0.5883, 14.680000, 37.977274, 23.737771, 23.6440, 3.0444, 0.6201, 14.720000, 37.977272, 23.737772, 24.0863, 3.0975, 0.6537, 14.760000, 37.977269, 23.737774, 24.5358, 3.1466, 0.6893, 14.800000, 37.977267, 23.737775, 24.9912, 3.1783, 0.7267, 14.840000, 37.977265, 23.737776, 25.4507, 3.2031, 0.7660, 14.880000, 37.977263, 23.737777, 25.9132, 3.2211, 0.8070, 14.920000, 37.977260, 23.737779, 26.3784, 3.2401, 0.8497, 14.960000, 37.977258, 23.737780, 26.8464, 3.2601, 0.8943, 15.000000, 37.977255, 23.737782, 27.3160, 3.2626, 0.9405, 15.040000, 37.977253, 23.737783, 27.7855, 3.2582, 0.9883, 15.080000, 37.977250, 23.737784, 28.2539, 3.2471, 1.0372, 15.120000, 37.977247, 23.737786, 28.7207, 3.2369, 1.0874, 15.160000, 37.977245, 23.737787, 29.1862, 3.2279, 1.1388, 15.200000, 37.977242, 23.737789, 29.6491, 3.2014, 1.1918, 15.240000, 37.977239, 23.737790, 30.1062, 3.1476, 1.2463, 15.280000, 37.977236, 23.737791, 30.5550, 3.0869, 1.3021, 15.320000, 37.977233, 23.737793, 30.9971, 3.0534, 1.3589, 15.360000, 37.977230, 23.737794, 31.4367, 3.0516, 1.4167, 15.400000, 37.977228, 23.737796, 31.8774, 3.0698, 1.4756, 15.440000, 37.977224, 23.737797, 32.3202, 3.0809, 1.5351, 15.480000, 37.977221, 23.737798, 32.7632, 3.0716, 1.5937, 15.520000, 37.977218, 23.737800, 33.2048, 3.0616, 1.6506, 15.560000, 37.977215, 23.737801, 33.6454, 3.0587, 1.7042, 15.600000, 37.977212, 23.737803, 34.0865, 3.0674, 1.7542, 15.640000, 37.977209, 23.737804, 34.5311, 3.1079, 1.8006, 15.680000, 37.977205, 23.737805, 34.9819, 3.1528, 1.8437, 15.720000, 37.977202, 23.737807, 35.4362, 3.1571, 1.8837, 15.760000, 37.977198, 23.737808, 35.8881, 3.1199, 1.9206, 15.800000, 37.977195, 23.737809, 36.3325, 3.0527, 1.9544, 15.840000, 37.977192, 23.737810, 36.7695, 3.0162, 1.9852, 15.880000, 37.977188, 23.737812, 37.2034, 3.0104, 2.0131, 15.920000, 37.977184, 23.737813, 37.6335, 2.9638, 2.0383, 15.960000, 37.977181, 23.737814, 38.0540, 2.8764, 2.0606, 16.000000, 37.977177, 23.737815, 38.4597, 2.7589, 2.0798, 16.040000, 37.977173, 23.737816, 38.8508, 2.6721, 2.0959, 16.080000, 37.977170, 23.737817, 39.2315, 2.6160, 2.1092, 16.120000, 37.977166, 23.737818, 39.6012, 2.5192, 2.1201, 16.160000, 37.977162, 23.737819, 39.9541, 2.3816, 2.1291, 16.200000, 37.977158, 23.737820, 40.2850, 2.2140, 2.1359, 16.240000, 37.977154, 23.737821, 40.5922, 2.0531, 2.1404, 16.280000, 37.977150, 23.737822, 40.8785, 1.9230, 2.1428, 16.320000, 37.977145, 23.737823, 41.1471, 1.8082, 2.1429, 16.360000, 37.977141, 23.737824, 41.3989, 1.6884, 2.1412, 16.400000, 37.977137, 23.737825, 41.6316, 1.5436, 2.1376, 16.440000, 37.977133, 23.737826, 41.8405, 1.3583, 2.1319, 16.480000, 37.977128, 23.737827, 42.0210, 1.1492, 2.1224, 16.520000, 37.977124, 23.737827, 42.1734, 0.9672, 2.1091, 16.560000, 37.977120, 23.737828, 42.3025, 0.8258, 2.0933, 16.600000, 37.977115, 23.737829, 42.4127, 0.7044, 2.0756, 16.640000, 37.977111, 23.737830, 42.5051, 0.5780, 2.0558, 16.680000, 37.977107, 23.737830, 42.5777, 0.4312, 2.0339, 16.720000, 37.977102, 23.737831, 42.6276, 0.2612, 2.0098, 16.760000, 37.977098, 23.737831, 42.6533, 0.0952, 1.9835, 16.800000, 37.977094, 23.737832, 42.6577, -0.0332, 1.9549, 16.840000, 37.977090, 23.737832, 42.6463, -0.1258, 1.9240, 16.880000, 37.977085, 23.737833, 42.6241, -0.1828, 1.8905, 16.920000, 37.977081, 23.737833, 42.5920, -0.2630, 1.8541, 16.960000, 37.977077, 23.737833, 42.5467, -0.3663, 1.8147, 17.000000, 37.977073, 23.737834, 42.4892, -0.4320, 1.7724, 17.040000, 37.977068, 23.737834, 42.4249, -0.4619, 1.7273, 17.080000, 37.977064, 23.737834, 42.3588, -0.4561, 1.6795, 17.120000, 37.977060, 23.737834, 42.2919, -0.4734, 1.6290, 17.160000, 37.977056, 23.737835, 42.2208, -0.5139, 1.5757, 17.200000, 37.977052, 23.737835, 42.1466, -0.5168, 1.5193, 17.240000, 37.977047, 23.737835, 42.0746, -0.4827, 1.4597, 17.280000, 37.977043, 23.737835, 42.0102, -0.4129, 1.3970, 17.320000, 37.977039, 23.737835, 41.9557, -0.3443, 1.3310, 17.360000, 37.977035, 23.737835, 41.9092, -0.3009, 1.2618, 17.400000, 37.977031, 23.737835, 41.8690, -0.2574, 1.1892, 17.440000, 37.977027, 23.737835, 41.8352, -0.2126, 1.1132, 17.480000, 37.977022, 23.737835, 41.8091, -0.1735, 1.0771, 17.520000, 37.977018, 23.737835, 41.7893, -0.1137, 1.0388, 17.560000, 37.977014, 23.737835, 41.7779, -0.0496, 0.9996, 17.600000, 37.977010, 23.737835, 41.7737, -0.0084, 0.9602, 17.640000, 37.977006, 23.737835, 41.7735, 0.0067, 0.9204, 17.680000, 37.977002, 23.737834, 41.7734, -0.0081, 0.8803, 17.720000, 37.976997, 23.737834, 41.7710, -0.0233, 0.8400, 17.760000, 37.976993, 23.737834, 41.7678, -0.0170, 0.7993, 17.800000, 37.976989, 23.737834, 41.7653, -0.0118, 0.7583, 17.840000, 37.976985, 23.737834, 41.7633, -0.0078, 0.7168, 17.880000, 37.976981, 23.737834, 41.7616, -0.0053, 0.6745, 17.920000, 37.976976, 23.737834, 41.7603, -0.0011, 0.6313, 17.960000, 37.976972, 23.737833, 41.7595, 0.0052, 0.5878, 18.000000,

Comment: There are no new lines `\n` in your csv? Also try sep='`, `'(a space after `,`)

Answer (score 0):

Your input file contains a space after each comma.
To omit them gracefully while reading, pass *skipinitialspace=True*
to *read_csv*.

Another hint: If the row that you provided in your post is really
the first row of your file (it contains just data, not column names),
then your file has no row with column names.

To inform *read_csv* about it, pass either *header=None*
or *names* with the proper list of column names.

And the last detail: Probably the first column of your source should be
the **index**. If this is the case, pass *index_col=[0]*.

Comment: Thanks, but I added skipinitialspace=True, no luck...